# Paypal Payflow Pro return url does not work correctly - 'processTransaction.do' appended - raises 404

Tags: python, paypal, payflowpro, returnurl, payflowlink

currently I am trying to migrate a working php paypal payflow implementation to a new python-based system.

I use secure token together with hosted checkout pages. The secure token works fine and I get redirected to the checkout page as well (although it has horrible formatting errors).

THE PROBLEM: after the payment it should redirect to the return url. This works BUT 'processTransaction.do' is appended to it. So my return url is defined as:
`'https://mywebsite.com/paypal/succes/'`
but i get redirected to
`'https://mywebsite.com/paypal/succes/processTransaction.do'`
and this raises a 404.

My secure token request parameters:

```
params = {}
params["PARTNER"] = "paypal"
params["VENDOR"] = "...."
params["TRXTYPE"] = "S"
params["AMT"] = payment_amount    #amount to pay
params["CREATESECURETOKEN"] = "Y"
params["SECURETOKENID"] = time.time() #needs to be unique
params["USER"] = "...."
params["PWD"] = "...."
```

Then I send the request and catch the return which looks like this:

```
RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=QQQc0rQZ8TkKSNMqU3Mg2og7o
SECURETOKENID=1431563231.24&RESPMSG=Approved
```

Afterwards I send the request for the checkout page with the following paramters:

```
params["SECURETOKEN"] = securetoken
params["SECURETOKENID"] = securetokenid
```

to: https://payflowpro.paypal.com

I use this code to send the requests:

```
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response_text = response.read()
```

The return url is set in the paypal manager with return type as POST and "Show Confirmation Page" is set to "On my website".

Does somebody know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: aparently paypal appends some kind of action to the url .... at least thats what it looks like ... just make a route rule to handle it ...

Comment: yes I could do that, but since I can pass the return url as parameter to paypal I expect the answer to be send to the url I specified. Also I can't find anything about this action in any documentation.

Comment: well i guarantee you arent ending up there by magic so A. paypal is redirecting to that url or B. you are redirecting to that url, those are really the only two possibilities ... (are you using some weird paypal for python library that might be doing this for you perhaps?) are you using `action` which was previously defined somehow to redirect? without seeing your code i doubt I can be much more help :/

Comment: I am pretty sure its paypal sending me there because I set the url in the paypal manager and not in my code. But anyways here is my code